# Give formulas whose interpretations in the model represent the predicates

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

sorry for this really stupid question.

Consider the structure $A=<\mathbb{N},<;\cdot,1>$ (arity type $<2;2,0>$). Give formulas whose interpretations in the model represent the predicates

(a) "$x_2$ is a divisor of $x_1$";

(b) "$x_1$ is prime";

(c) "for every $n$, there is some prime greater than $n$".

---

**Solutions:**

So let us begin with (a) and then work our way to (c):
(a) First of all I have some question marks: If I am correct, I would like to express $x_1=x_3\cdot x_2$. Is it then correct to write something like this  $$\forall x_1\exists (x_2\land x_3)(x_1\doteq f_1(x_3,x_2))?$$

I mean, every natural number can be written as factors, may it be 1 times itself or any other number, every natural number can be written as factors. Therefor i choose to write $\forall x_1$. Then I choose to write that there exists some natural number $x_2$ and some natural number $x_3$ such that this property holds. Is this the correct way to express that $x_2$ is a divisor of $x_1$? Also is $\exists (x_2\land x_3)$ the same as $\exists x_2\land\exists x_3$?

If this is the correct way of saying it, let's head over to (b) where i want to express that $x_1$ is a prime number. I suppose my goal is to use (a) and say that "okey, every divisor of $x_1$ is either 1 or $x_1$". But how would I go on and write that? I guess I could do it something like this $\exists (x_1\land x_2)\text{ ... } (x_1\doteq f_1(f_2,x_2)\lor x_1\doteq f_1(x_1,x_2))$ Where I am not quite sure what I should substitute for $...$ I want somehow to express "for every divisor of $x_1$". Should I do it something like this, to express every divisor of $x_1$? $\forall (x_1=f_1(x_3,x_2))$? If not, what's wrong? Or perhaps everything i wrote is wrong? :) Lastly, for (c), I suppose I have to write it something like this: $\forall n\exists x_1(P(n,\varphi))$ where $\varphi$ is the formula for the prime number?

What am I doing wrong here? What have I mistunderstood? I want to become better at understanding how you can make formulas out of statements and vice versa and really hope someone can help me, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few problems going on. First, notation: "$\exists (x_2\land x_3)$", even as part of a formula, is not well-formed. You'd write "$\exists x_2 \exists x_3$" or "$\exists x_2, x_3$".

Semi-formally, how would you express "x divides y"? Well, x divides y *iff* there's a $z$ such that $y = x \cdot z$. Can you express that in a formula, $\mathsf{D}(x, y)$?

Similarly, x is prime *iff* $x > 1$ and for all $v$, if $v$ divides $x$ then $v = 1$ or $v = x$. Now express that in a formula $\mathsf{P}(x)$ which makes use of $\mathsf{D}(x)$.

Similarly for (c).

Comment: So you mean there's something wrong with my answer to (a)? For (b) I still feel pretty unsure but i have made an attempt, here's how my attempt looks... $\exists x_1, x_2\forall v(P(f_2,x_1)\land x_1\doteq f_1(v,x_2)\to v\doteq 1\land v\doteq x)$. When you type iff, in my head it looks something like this $x\leftrightarrow\exists x_1, x_2\forall v(P(f_2,x_1)\land x_1\doteq f_1(v,x_2)\to v\doteq 1\land v\doteq x)$ but this seems kinda odd to me. I must have misunderstood something :)

Comment: oops, a typo/oversight I just corrected: "... a formula,  (x,y)" not "D(x)".

Comment: I'm utterly confused by your notation. Whatever are $f_1, f_2$? and why are they sometimes variables, other times apparently function symbols? They're not part of the 1st order language for the structure in question so get rid of them. In your attempt at (b), the whole "∧x1≐f1(v,x2)" part looks useless and anyway wrong; get rid of it. You need $x_1$ to be a free variable as you're trying to define a formula that characterizes "$x_1$ is prime". "P(f2,x1)" should be "$D(v, x_1)$" where "D" is the "divides" formula of (a). Finally, "$\wedge$" \wedge means "and", you want "$\vee$" \vee for "or"...

Comment: Ok, but in the logic course I am attending right now the professor wants us to use $f_1$ for multiplication and $f_2$ for 1 (for this case)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_predicate. Where the explanation says "function symbol, is a logical symbol that may be applied to an object term to produce another object term" and so $x_1\cdot x_2$ produces another term

Comment: Ohh OK so they *are* function symbols. But then $f_2$ has no business being an argument to $P$. Continuing previous comment: If you did (a), you have a formula with free variables $x_2, x_1$ expressing "$x_2$ divides $x_1$". I'm sure you're supposed to give that formula a name, shorthand – I suggested $D(x_2, x_1)$ – and use it in (b). In (a) you'll need $f_1$ only. In (b), if you use $D(x2, x1)$, you'll only need $f_2$, explicitly, and you'll only have one bound variable, $x_2$, at the front, with a *universal* quantifier. Is there some reason you're writing $\doteq$ rather than just = ??

Comment: yeah there's some reason, can't remember the exact reason right now ;)

Comment: Prof's requirement for now? Probably. Just to get you to clearly distinguish between the formal language and the intuitive notions (of multiplication, 1, and equality). He has a point.

Comment: So please disregard what I said 2 comments ago: $f_2$ *does* have some business being an argument to things, though $f_1$ would not (in a 1st order language). It is unusual to use $f_i$ for a constant when other $f_j$ are used for functions. Yes you can claim that "constants are 0-ary functions" but then for consistency you should have to write "$f_1()$" especially when the exercise is trying to be so explicit, formal and... fussy.

Comment: It's okay, I should perhaps be more clear about the meaning of every symbol I use

Comment: It's good when you're learning this material, as it helps you distinguish clearly between syntax and semantics. This problem is all about that distinction, as well as the interplay between them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30187/discussion-between-briano-and-joel).