# Proofing with predicate logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Please solve this step by step. I have a test coming up and this is the only problem I cannot solve. Assume that the universe of discourse is the set of natural numbers. Let <(x,y) denote the predicate constant "x is less than y" and |(x, y) denote the predicate constant "x divides y" (i.e., y is a multiple of x). Express the assertion "x is a prime" by using only the two predicate constants together with logical connectives, quantifiers, individual variables, constant values, parentheses and brackets. Note that it is not allowed to define additional predicates.

```
[Grading Guidelines]
```

3 points    for correctly expressing "x greater than 1"

7 points    for correctly expressing the non-existence of a divisor k

5 points    for correctly expressing "k divides x"

5 points    for correctly expressing "k other than 1 and x"

Comment: I thought at first this question is a possible duplicate of [Give formulas whose interpretations in the model represent the predicates](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477071/give-formulas-whose-interpretations-in-the-model-represent-the-predicates). It's not quite the same, but anyway, that Q/A is relevant.

Comment: This is all that was in the question. I was given an answer but something is wrong with it. 
Assertion To Be Expressed:
"A natural number x is a prime."

Remark: A prime number is defined as an integer greater than 1 that
  has no positive divisor other than 1 and itself.


Straightforward Translation of the Definition:

<(1,x) âˆ§ Â¬ âˆƒk [ <(1,k) âˆ§ <(k,x) âˆ§ |(k,x) ]

Comment: OK then you have to define predicates IsZero(x) – there is y such that (*for all z, <(y, z) or y = z), and x = y" -- and then Is1(x) -- "x is not zero and everything y that's not zero is ≥ x".

Comment: How would I do this? I have absolutely no clue. Predicate logic is not my easiest type.

Comment: What's wrong with the answer you were given, the alleged "Straightforward Translation of the Definition", is that it got turned into gibberish. "§" isn't a logical symbol, 'a' and 'A' have hats, and so on. Unicode conversion problems, possibly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem mentions constants among the only things that you're entitled to use, though it doesn't mention any in particular. I'm going to assume that you have a constant for 1. If you don't, things get very gory: while you can define "x is 1" by a formula, you have to use it in two places in a formula defining "x is prime", so the latter becomes very long and hard to write and read.

Even though not all of these steps are needed to express "x is prime", here are the four initial steps:

- *x is greater than 1*: $<(1, x))$
- *non-existence of a divisor of x*: $\forall k \neg \space |(k, x)$
- *k divides x*: $|(k, x)$
- *k is other than 1 or x*: $\neg k = 1 \wedge \neg k = x$

Usually "$\neq$" can be used as an abbreviation, and then the last one would be $k \neq 1 \wedge k \neq x$.

Finally,

> *x is prime*: $<(1,x) \wedge \forall y(|(y, x) \to (y = 1 \vee y = k))$

In words: *x is greater than 1, and anything that divides x is either 1 or x*. If the goal is to use those four preliminary predicates whenever possible, you could "turn around" the matrix of this formula to say: *x > 1, and anything that's other than 1 or x doesn't divide x*: $$<(1,x) \wedge \forall y((y \neq 1 \wedge y \neq k) \to \neg |(y, x))$$

Comment: And if we have (as I imagine) "$=$", it seems to me that : "$n$ is a *prime*" is definable as : $<(1,n) \land \forall m [ | (m,n) \to (m=1 \lor m=n)]$.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't appear that we have a '1' constant. But OP has to clarify this. I love deleting stuff, I'd happily cut the answer down to 1/5 of its size.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA I decided that surely there is a constant for 1: without it, the problem is a mild form of torture, especially because "it is not allowed to define additional predicates".